# Canvas - fade in speed?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Being a newbie in canvas I'm just trying to figure out how to manage fade-ins/outs.
So far I have come up with quite obvious solution:

```
var alpha = 0.01;
        c.globalAlpha = alpha;
        c.font="44px Georgia";
        c.fillStyle = '#fff';
        c.fillText("Ave Satani!!",120,250);
        if(alpha < 1.0)
        {

        alpha += 0.01;  
        requestAnimationFrame(draw);    
            }
```

Though it doesn't allow me to set the animation speed and it is way too fast.
Any tips? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Make the change of alpha a function of time. Then it will be obvious how to change speed. It's not obvious what is `draw` as well

Comment: "draw"  - is a function. this code is a mere snippet from a banner animation.
"Make the change of alpha a function of time"  - I am sorry, buddy, but Ihave no clue how can that be done...

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Ld5oque8/ - as you can see the width is calculated as a function of time here

Comment: ah! I see..yeah, that's a solution! Thank you
maybe, any other suggestions? a bit complicated way (though 100% working, yeah!) Thanks, man!

Comment: Well, since you asked...In my subjective experience, the human eye visually "fills in the opacity" after text is 40-60% opaque.  So I would fade-In from 0-60% more slowly and fade-in the remaining 61-100% more quickly.  I'm not quite sure what causes this effect--maybe the eye is so used to reading text that the brain has been trained to fill the 61-100% just based on the first 60%.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you just need to slower down the alpha value increment. so you can use another variable to slowerdown the speed

http://jsfiddle.net/dlinx/968y1e3z/
Here is what you want, lesser the speed value, faster the transition, higher the value, slower the animation.

```
var c = document.getElementById("can").getContext("2d");
var alpha = 0.01;
var i=0,speed=10;
c.globalAlpha = 0;

draw();
function draw() {
    c.globalAlpha = alpha;
    c.font = "44px Georgia";
    c.fillStyle = '#000';
    c.fillText("Ave Satani!!", 120, 250);
    i+=1;
    if (alpha < 1.0 ) {
        if(i%speed===0)
        alpha += 0.001;
        requestAnimationFrame(draw);
    }
}
```